# odoo 13 create domain from a custom field in `sale.subscription`

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

hi am new to odoo development, this may be something simple but I can't figure it out

I added a new field `subscription_tier` to the `sale.subscription` model

```
class subscription_tire_set(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.subscription'

    @api.depends('recurring_invoice_line_ids.product_id')
    def _compute_subscription_tire(self):
        # code for computing

        n_subscription.subscription_tier = result 

    subscription_tier = fields.Char(string='Subscription Tier', readonly=True, compute='_compute_subscription_tire')
```

In my custom model, I added

```
    @api.onchange('user_name')
    def onchange_test_domain_fiedl(self):
        obj = self.search([])
        available_ids = []
        for i in obj:
            available_ids.append(i.user_name.id)

        return {'domain': {'user_name': [&,|,('id', 'not in', available_ids),(('subscription_tier','=','tier_i'),('subscription_tier','=','tier_ii'),('subscription_tier','=','tier_iii'))]}}



    user_name = fields.Many2one('sale.subscription', string='Name')
```

Comment: Can you correct the indentation and add ``test_domain` field?

Comment: You can combine the three `subscription_tier` expressions in one expression `[('id', 'not in', 'available_ids'), '|', ('subscription_tier', 'in', ['tier_i', 'tier_ii', 'tier_iii'])]`

Comment: do you mean like this @Kenly

Comment: I added more details about `subscription_tier` in case the problem is there @Kenly

Comment: I asked for `test_domain` field. Is the indentation of `return` correct?

Comment: I used this https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/remove-value-from-many2one-fields-if-that-value-is-already-in-any-form-records-114403

Comment: and replaced `test_domain` with `user_name`

Comment: I edited your code to make like the answer in the provided link.

Comment: when i applied your changes i got this error
ValueError: Invalid domain term ('id', 'not in', 'available_ids')
can you please post and answer and change the code there @Kenly

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that you changer `available_ids` to a string. corrected.

Comment: not working i can see all

Comment: This does mean that all subscriptions have one of the three values specified in the domain?

Comment: no, only one has it the rest is empty

Comment: Check the value of `available_ids` and remember to reload.

Comment: how to Check the value and yes I do upgrade and reload after every change

Comment: Use `logging.warning('available_ids %s', available_ids)`

Comment: `Non-stored field sale.subscription.subscription_tier cannot be searched.` in the terminal log

Comment: Locate `subscription_tier ` field and add `store=True`.

Comment: yes it works now, can you explain what is the difference

Comment: also, I changed this `{'user_name': ['|', ('id', 'not in', available_ids)` ro `{'user_name': ['&', ('id', 'not in', available_ids)`

Comment: since I am using `in` there is no need for `|` right? both conditions have to be met @Kenly

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Computed fields are not stored by default, they are computed and returned when requested. Setting `store=True` will store them in the database and automatically enable searching.

searching on a computed field can also be enabled by setting the `search` parameter.. You can read more at [Computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214051/discussion-between-kenly-and-moaz-mabrok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `OR` on one field, you can use domain `in` operator so the following domain:

```
['|', ('subscription_tier','=','tier_i'),'|', ('subscription_tier','=','tier_ii'),('subscription_tier','=','tier_iii')]
```

Can be reduced to :

```
[('subscription_tier','in', ['tier_i', 'tier_ii', 'tier_iii'])]
```

[Computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) are not stored by default, they are computed and returned when requested. Setting `store=True` will store them in the database and automatically enable searching. searching on a computed field can also be enabled by setting the search parameter.

Try to set **subscription_tier** `store` attribute to `True` to enable searching.